# Query values in a Dictionary<ObjectId, Class> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Consider the following simple example of Students and Teachers;

```
// person
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person() {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(DateTime.Now);
    }
}

// student has a Classroom
public class Student : Person
{
    public string Classroom { get; set; }
}

// teacher has a Dictionary<ObjectId, Student> Students
public class Teacher : Person
{
    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    public Dictionary<ObjectId, Student> Students { get; set; }
    public Teacher() {
        Students = new Dictionary<ObjectId, Student>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/database?safe=true");
        var database = server.GetDatabase("sandbox");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Teacher>("teachers");
        collection.Drop();

        // create students
        var s1 = new Student() { Name = "s1", Classroom = "foo" };
        var s2 = new Student() { Name = "s2", Classroom = "foo" };
        var s3 = new Student() { Name = "s3", Classroom = "baz" };
        var s4 = new Student() { Name = "s4", Classroom = "foo" };

        // teacher 1
        var t1 = new Teacher() { Name = "t1" };
        t1.Students.Add(s1.Id, s1);
        t1.Students.Add(s2.Id, s2);
        collection.Insert(t1);

        // teacher 2
        var t2 = new Teacher {Name = "t2"};
        t2.Students.Add(s3.Id, s3);
        collection.Insert(t2);

        // add teacher 3 
        var t3 = new Teacher() {Name = "t3"};
        t3.Students.Add(s4.Id, s4);
        collection.Insert(t3);

        // select via key
        var onlyt1 = collection.AsQueryable().Where(t => t.Students.ContainsKey(s1.Id)).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("onlyt1 : {0}", onlyt1.ToJson());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I can select via the key (shown above), but how do I find all the teachers who have students with classroom of "foo"? I want to write something like;

```
// select via value
var shouldBeJustT1andT3 = collection.AsQueryable().Where(t => t.Students.Values.Where(s => s.Classroom == "foo")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Any* to get any teacher for whom there are students in a given classroom "foo":

```
List<Teacher> shouldBeJustT1andT3 = collection.Where(
    teacher => teacher.Students.Any(student => student.Classroom == "foo")
).ToList();
```

---

**Edit**

Since Mongo's IQueryable isn't supporting *Any* by default, maybe you could just use `Where` and `Count` instead of `Any`:

```
List<Teacher> shouldBeJustT1andT3 = collection.Where(
    teacher => teacher.Students.Where(student => student.Classroom == "foo").Count() > 0
).ToList();
```

Comment: I changed the Linq to; `collection.AsQueryable().Where(teacher => teacher.Students.Any(student => student.Value.Classroom == "foo")).ToList();`

And I now get the error;
`Any requires that the serializer specified for Students support items by implementing MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonArraySerializer and returning a non-null result. MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializer`2[MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId,EntitySandbox.Student] is the current serializer.`

Comment: @madebybear I'm not sure how hard it is to implement `IBsonArraySerializer`.  Please see my update above, maybe that will work.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I have another error now; `Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: Enumerable.Count<KeyValuePair<ObjectId, Student>>(Enumerable.Where<KeyValuePair<ObjectId, Student>>(teacher.Students, (KeyValuePair<ObjectId, Student> student) => (student.Value.Classroom == "foo")))`

I'm going to download the driver source and see if I can get some clues.

Comment: @madebybear maybe also check if it's easy to implement that interface it's asking for?  http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.5/html/64605e69-43e9-3d6a-97b8-8bd6071d7c61.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have `Students` of type just `ICollection<Person>`?

Then you don't need query dictionary's values but flat objects' list, i.e. `where s.ID == x && s.Classroom == "blah"`.

Dictionary makes sense to find object by key only, i.e. `t.Students[studentId]`.

---

To find teachers: *see dbaseman's answer, he's correct.*

Comment: I could just use an ICollection, however, I wanted to ensure that a teacher could not have the same student key twice.

Comment: @madebybear: shouldn't the storage ensure/force such constraint?

Comment: yes, for a teacher. I wanted to store n students as a property of the teacher though.

Comment: @madebybear: Can different teachers have the same student? I guess yes. Then not 'store' but 'represent', right?